# why it's permitted to redefine a global operator new(size_t)?

Tags: c++

why it's permitted to redefine a global `operator new(size_t)`?

As far as i know,there exists an identical and default **`operator new(size_t`)** in c++ standard library(learned from c++ Primer 5th)

The **default operator new** is in global namespace,so why does the **user-defined global operator new** does not **conflict** with the default one?Since they are in the same scope,isn't there a redefinition error?

Comment: Why blockquote?

Comment: Which "scope"? No, you only blockquote if you're quoting something. To separate between paragraphs you only need to double-newline.

Comment: The short answer is "because the C++ standard explicitly allows a user-defined global operator new to replace the default one".

Comment: @user202729 thanks for your reminding,i've amended.

Comment: @Peter So the rule of ODR does not apply in this situation,just because the standard allow this behavior?

Comment: This is an explicit provision in the standard, so would qualify as a special case of the ODR.   Within any program, only one definition of each `operator new` is permitted.   So either the default or a replacement for each `operator new` can be used within an entire program.    No program can use both (e.g. the default in some compilation units, and a replacement in another compilation unit), and no program can use two distinct replacements of the same `operator new`.

Answer (score 6):

The standard ( Language support library -> Dynamic memory management ) says for these functions:

[[new.delete.single]](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/support.dynamic#new.delete.single-2)

> Replaceable: A C++ program may define functions with either of these
> function signatures, and thereby displace the default versions defined
> by the C++ standard library.

[[replacement.functions]](http://eel.is/c++draft/replacement.functions)

> The program's definitions are used instead of the default versions
> supplied by the implementation ([support.dynamic]). Such replacement
> occurs prior to program startup ([basic.def.odr], [basic.start]). The
> program's declarations shall not be specified as inline.
>
> No diagnostic is required.

[[defns.replacement]](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.replacement)

> Replacement function
>
> non-reserved function whose
> definition is provided by a C++ program [ Note: Only one definition
> for such a function is in effect for the duration of the program's
> execution, as the result of creating the program ([lex.phases]) and
> resolving the definitions of all translation units ([basic.link]).
> — end note  ]

Comment: It would be nice to also explain why the ODR does not apply to functions defined in the C++ standard library. I think that's what the OP is really confused about.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException How's that?

Comment: Thanks a lot,i think **replacement occurs prior to program startup** is the point

Comment: @choxsword which can also mean, during linking. For me the key is: No diagnostic is required..